# How to fix blank pagination links?

Tags: php, functions, pagination

I am working on a Wordpress blog that has what appears to be custom pagination for the posts. [As you can see here](http://transamericanautoparts.com/company-news) the correct amount of links are being rendered at the bottom of the page, however those links are blank. Here is the code in the `functions.php`

```
function emm_paginate($args = null) {
    $defaults = array(
        'page' => null, 'pages' => null, 
        'range' => 3, 'gap' => 3, 'anchor' => 1,
        'before' => '<div class="emm-paginate">', 'after' => '</div>',
        'title' => __('Pages:'),
        'nextpage' => __('&raquo;'), 'previouspage' => __('&laquo'),
        'echo' => 1
    );

    $r = wp_parse_args($args, $defaults);
    extract($r, EXTR_SKIP);

    if (!$page && !$pages) {
        global $wp_query;

        $page = get_query_var('paged');
        $page = !empty($page) ? intval($page) : 1;

        $posts_per_page = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
        $pages = intval(ceil($wp_query->found_posts / $posts_per_page));
    }

    $output = "";
    if ($pages > 1) {   
        $output .= "$before<span class='emm-title'>$title</span>";
        $ellipsis = "<span class='emm-gap'>...</span>";

        if ($page > 1 && !empty($previouspage)) {
            $output .= "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($page - 1) . "' class='emm-prev'>$previouspage</a>";
        }

        $min_links = $range * 2 + 1;
        $block_min = min($page - $range, $pages - $min_links);
        $block_high = max($page + $range, $min_links);
        $left_gap = (($block_min - $anchor - $gap) > 0) ? true : false;
        $right_gap = (($block_high + $anchor + $gap) < $pages) ? true : false;

        if ($left_gap && !$right_gap) {
            $output .= sprintf('%s%s%s', 
                emm_paginate_loop(1, $anchor), 
                $ellipsis, 
                emm_paginate_loop($block_min, $pages, $page)
            );
        }
        else if ($left_gap && $right_gap) {
            $output .= sprintf('%s%s%s%s%s', 
                emm_paginate_loop(1, $anchor), 
                $ellipsis, 
                emm_paginate_loop($block_min, $block_high, $page), 
                $ellipsis, 
                emm_paginate_loop(($pages - $anchor + 1), $pages)
            );
        }
        else if ($right_gap && !$left_gap) {
            $output .= sprintf('%s%s%s', 
                emm_paginate_loop(1, $block_high, $page),
                $ellipsis,
                emm_paginate_loop(($pages - $anchor + 1), $pages)
            );
        }
        else {
            $output .= emm_paginate_loop(1, $pages, $page);
        }

        if ($page < $pages && !empty($nextpage)) {
            $output .= "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($page + 1) . "' class='emm-next'>$nextpage</a>";
        }

        $output .= $after;
    }

    if ($echo) {
        echo $output;
    }

    return $output;
}

/**
 * Helper function for pagination which builds the page links.
 *
 * @access private
 *
 * @author Eric Martin <eric@ericmmartin.com>
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2009, Eric Martin
 * @version 1.0
 *
 * @param int $start The first link page.
 * @param int $max The last link page.
 * @return int $page Optional, default is 0. The current page.
 */
function emm_paginate_loop($start, $max, $page = 0) {
    $output = "";
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        $output .= ($page === intval($i)) 
            ? "<span class='emm-page emm-current'>$i</span>" 
            : "<a href='" . get_pagenum_link($i) . "' class='emm-page'>$i</a>";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

****EDIT****

I've deleted that emm function out of my `functions.php` and `index.php` and added

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
                'mid_size' => 2,
                'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'textdomain' ),
                'next_text' => __( 'Onward', 'textdomain' ),
            ) ); ?>
```

to my `index.php` and same problem. Numbers are showing up and yielding blank pages. I also noticed my `archives.php` was missing from the root folder. Added it and still nothing.

Comment: are you using the default loop to output posts or a custom query in the template?

Answer (score 0):

Could you go to this page for us:

../wp-admin/options-permalink.php

What is the structure chosen?  That will give you the answer for how to adjust the function on the bottom

edit: Also, Why is this part like this:

```
 if ($echo) {
    echo $output;
}

return $output;
}
```

Shouldn't $output be in parenthesis?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer but is this what you are asking for? <?php
if ( is_multisite() && !is_subdomain_install() && is_main_site() ) {
 $permalink_structure = preg_replace( '|^/?blog|', '', $permalink_structure );
 $category_base = preg_replace( '|^/?blog|', '', $category_base );
 $tag_base = preg_replace( '|^/?blog|', '', $tag_base );
} Also not sure if $output should be in perenbthesis and which $output? There are two.